# sympy の関数をmatplotlibでプロットしたい

Tags: python3, matplotlib, sympy

以下のようなコードを書きました。そして、`X[0]`は関数なので、`plt.plot(X[0](t),t)`のようにプロットしたいのですが、どうやらsympyのオブジェクトは呼び出せないっぽいです。どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```py
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
A = sp.Matrix([[-1, 0], [0, -1]])
X0 = sp.Matrix([[1], [0]])
    
t = sp.symbols("t")
At = A*t

X = At.exp()*X0
x1 = X[0]
x2 = X[1]
```

Comment: sympyで(中でmatplotlibを使って?)なんとかなりそうな感じがあります。[Plotting](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html), [読書ノート » SymPy 利用ノート » プロットを利用する](https://showa-yojyo.github.io/notebook/python-sympy/plotting.html), [お気楽 SymPy プログラミング超入門 - NCT](http://www.nct9.ne.jp/m_hiroi/light/sympy01.html), [Pythonで数学の勉強：matplotlibでsympy(scipy)のグラフを描く](https://qiita.com/tibigame/items/0e48673179aeeab55a43)

Comment: spとは何のことでしょうか？

Comment: @岡田恵 さん、sympy の略では？ タイトルと質問文は合っているので、ソースのimportが転記ミスでしょう。

Comment: [sympy.plotting.plot.Plot](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.Plot) でよろしいのではないかと。`sp.plot(X[0], (t, -1, 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matplotlibで描画するなら実数が必要かと思います。
t=1としたときの例です。

```
plt.plot(1, X[0].subs(t, 1), 'o')
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし、これでは一つずつしか代入出来ず、グラフのプロットをforループで回さなければなりません。それは大変ではありませんか？

Comment: 何が｢大変｣なのでしょうか？ループ処理では実行時間がかかるのでは？と懸念されているのでしょうか？グラフ化したいデータは膨大なのでしょうか？